# Doubt about package-by-feature and circular dependencies

Tags: java, architecture, dependencies, packages, circular-dependency

I am implementing a library that:

1. Takes some input data (I put data structures and classes in the `parsing` package)
2. Stores the data in a structure (I put data structures and classes in the `storage` package)
3. Present the data in some meaningful way (`chart` package)

I divided my code this way because if I want to add another data representation (for example a `table` package) I can reuse `parsing` and `storage` packages.

I am though worried about circular dependencies:

- My `Parser` should store input data in a dedicated data structure class, `Record`, this means that `DataStorage` has to know how to get data from it and that Parser should know how data insertion is performed in `DataStorage` class.
- I am also concerned that the `chart` - and eventually `table` as well - package should know a bit more about how to get data from my `DataStorage` class.

Are my concerns valid? If yes, how could I solve the issue? 
I was thinking to expose some Interfaces in a `contracts`/`interfaces` package in such a way that specific classes such as `Record` and `DataStorage` would implement them and there wouldn't be a circular dependency anymore.

Would this solution be considered a good practice or are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

> I was thinking to expose some Interfaces in a contracts/interfaces
>   package in such a way that specific classes such as `Record` and
>   `DataStorage` would implement them and there wouldn't be a circular
>   dependency anymore.

This is fine. Each package defines (in the more abstract way possible<sup>1</sup>) the inputs and outputs so the dependency upon these packages is implemented by *dependency inversion*. This is a clean dependency relationship between the package and consumers because both remain fairly decoupled from each other.

That said, *package-by-feature* is still sensible to the fact that, sometimes, we have cross-cutting concerns throttling between boundaries (packages, modules, layers, etc). The alternative then could be a different organization. Something similar to *[package-by-component](http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2015/03/08/package_by_component_and_architecturally_aligned_testing.html)*<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1: In line with this, it might interest *[the dependency rule: which data crosses the boundaries](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2832399)*</sup>

<sup>2: For small boundaries such as libraries or small units of business *package-by-feature* works fine but when it comes to modular architectures, *package-by-component* makes a big deal. Think in small built-in features vs add-ons or plug-ins.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be careful about masking the cycle with interfaces.

I would recommend to let the storage know about the parser, but not the other way around. The parser seems to be your domain / business logic. Everything else revolves around it. Also see [The Onion Architecture](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).

You can create a new package that orchestrates everything (e.g. app). But the transformation from "parser" to "storage" is probably very dependent on the storage system. So I think it belongs either in the "storage" package or in a "parserstorage" package.

When your parser generates so many data that it is from a performance perspective necessary to intertwine it with the storage, you can define interfaces for storage in the parser package and implement them in a "storage flavor" package.

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependencies can be an indicator that the **which-class-is-responsible-for** of your architecture is not correct.

Usually you have

- technical components (like csv-parser or html-table-display) and
- business-domain-components (i.e. product-data) constisting of

  - data-items (the product values like name, description, price),
  - data-repositories (to save an load the product-data from/to csv (using your csv-parser) and/or database)
  - data-gui (edit, list (using your html-table-display), ... products in a form)
  - either services or mvc-models (i.e. load product-items from csv-repository do some processing and/or save to database-repository or display result)

This architecture avoids circular dependencies as

- technical components have no knowledge about domain-components.
- coordination between the classes are done in service and/or model

This Example whould be packaged into

- two technical components

  - io (containing the csv-parser),
  - html-tools (containing the html-table tools))
- and one business-domain-component

  - productdata (which you can load/save from csv/database and display as list on a web page)